# resignFirstResponder - can not remove keyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a multi view app, to swap views I use:

```
-(IBAction) goSecond{
[self presentModalViewController:secondviewController animated:YES]

}
```

On this view I have a text field that the user will enter a number, but I con not get the keyboard to remove from the view. I have read several posts but can get this to work. I use:

```
-(IBAction) goAwayKey: (id) sender{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction) tapBack: (id) sender{
[textField1 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

In secondviewController.h I have

```
-(BOOL) disableAutomaticKeyboardDismissal;
```

and in secondviewController.m

```
-(BOOL) disableAutomaticKeyboardDismissal{

return NO;

}
```

I still cant get the keyboard to go away, is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `[self.view endEditing:YES];` might be useful to you, means you need only know the view - not the specific field.

Comment: How are you calling goAwayKey()? Did you wire up your IBAction correctly to your interface?

Comment: @vipinagg I have 2 actions, for goAwayKey I used the did end on exit event to files owner. For Tapback I made the view a UIControl and used touch down and connected to files owner. Still can't get the keyboard to remove. If I use the default keyboard the done button functions correctly but I need to use the Number pad so need to get the tapBack action to work. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically,

```
 [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
```

should work fair enough, are you sure that your methods are being called? Place a breakpoint in both methods to resign and check if they are called, that will give us some clues about your problem.

Comment: Inserted Breakpoints at both actions, the goAwayKey is never called, selecting the done button has no action.  The tapBackG (user tapping the backgroup) is recognised GDB stopped at breakpoint 2 (hit count 1)- '-tapBackG'. Keyboard is still not removed.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, this issue was caused by the outlet not being linked correctly. reworking the links resolved this.